# Facebook publish_actions aproved but grantedScope shows publish_actions only for me

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having an interesting issue. 
My FB Canvas game is in dev mode and i have gotten my publish_actions approval. When launch my game in the browser i get the list of grantedScopes when logged into my account it lists publish_actions correctly and everything works, but when one of my testers (i have given the person the tester roll in the fb dev console.) Loads up the game then it does not list publish_actions under their grantedScopes. 
Am i doing something wrong? 
Do I need to request of the user to accept this new  permission somehow?

here is my fblogin code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Facebook.Unity;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class FBLogin : MonoBehaviour {

void Awake()
{
    FB.Init (SetInit, OnHideUnity);
}

private void SetInit()
{

    Debug.Log ("FB Init done.");

    if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
    {
        Debug.Log ("FB Logged In.");
    }else{
        Debug.Log("FB NOT Logged In.");
    }
}

private void OnHideUnity(bool isGameShown)
{
    if(!isGameShown)
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    }else{
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }
}

public void FBlogin ()
{
    var perms = new List<string>(){"public_profile", "email",};
    FB.LogInWithPublishPermissions(perms, AuthCallback);
}

private void AuthCallback (ILoginResult result) 
{
    Debug.Log(result.RawResult);
    if (FB.IsLoggedIn) 
    {

        var aToken = Facebook.Unity.AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;
        // Print current access token's User ID
        Debug.Log(aToken.UserId);
        // Print current access token's granted permissions
        foreach (string perm in aToken.Permissions) {
            Debug.Log(perm);
        }
    } else {
        Debug.Log("User cancelled login");

    }
}
}
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: You really do need to post your code if we are going to be able to help...

Comment: You of course need to _ask_ users for that permission.

Comment: i have added my login code to the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions you are requesting are not publish permissions, they are read permissions.  You will need to use

`FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(new List<String>(){"public_profile", "email"}, AuthCallback)`

to log in with the requested read permissions.  Once your callback fires, you will need to submit a second request:

`FB.LogInWithPublishPermissions(new List<String>(){"publish_actions"}, AuthCallback)`

You cannot combine read and publish permissions on the same request dialog to the end user.  Rather than open two dialogs back to back, it is considered best practice to hold off on requesting the publish permissions until the user actually attempts to publish something from within your app.